# Action of EtONa/EtOH on compound containing -CN group

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, reagents

[image]

In the above question, I know compound A will be prepared by just replacing -Cl with -CN group in the starting compound. I wanted to know what work would be **C$_2$H$_5$ONa/EtOH** doing in order to make compound B?

I have seen this **C$_2$H$_5$ONa/EtOH** to perform elimination reactions on alkyl halides forming alkenes but no idea how will it react with benzene containing **-CN** group.

**NOTE : The original compound should be as given below**

[image]

Comment: This looks to me that someone has either drawn up a reaction scheme with an extra methylene group in it, or they haven't looked at the pKa tables. What do other people think?

Comment: @Waylander: I agree that the chloride has an extra methylene group given the way the structure is drawn. Otherwise, what purpose would benzaldehyde serve. EtONa/EtOH itself without water is not going to effect hydrolysis.

Comment: @Waylander maybe the compound should not contain it. you can proceed without the extra methylene group. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Waylander doesn't it look like the ethoxide will form a carbanion next to the CN group, like what happens in an aldol reaction? I agree, though, that it would form better next to a phenyl group, otherwise the benzene ring has no use

Comment: @TRC ethoxide is nowhere near strong enough to deprotonate an unactivated nitrile - hence my comment above about pKa tables

Comment: You might want to google "ivanov phenylacetonitrile" and look at the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that the phenethyl chloride is meant to be benzyl chloride then this is the solution I believe the question setter is looking for:

A is phenylacetonitrile which is deprotonated by ethoxide and condenses with the benzaldehyde to give benzylic alcohol B. The acid conditions dehydrate B to give the 1,2-diphenyl-cyanoalkene C (or if pushed hard enough the unsaturated acid). The $\ce{SOCl2}$ followed by $\ce{MeNH2}$ forms the chloride from the alcohol which is displaced by the methylamine to give the $\alpha-$N-Methylamino-nitrile.

As shown by the discussions below there is considerable doubt about whether this reaction sequence has any basis in reality.

Comment: I didn't understand how A condenses with benzaldehyde to give benzylic alcohol. Can you share a mechanism?

Comment: Much like an aldol only the nucleophilic species is the nitrile anion rather than the enoalte.

Comment: I'd opt for B being the unsaturated nitrile via loss of water from the initial adduct.

Comment: @user55119 in which case, what is the SOCl2 reaction with B?

Comment: Good point! Missed that. The problem is, in IMO, conceptual. A Chem. Abst. search of the reaction between PhCH2CN and PhCHO to form the adduct can be initiated with kinetic bases, CeCl3 or Rh(I). There is a plethora of conditions for the condensation to form the unsaturated nitrile. The postulated chloride derived from either the phenyl acetonitrile or the propionitrile is unknown. The latter is a viable product but not the former, where elimination by methylamine is likely. continued..

Comment: ... I could find no conjugate additions of amines to PhCH=C(Ph)CN. The problem is an exercise in individual reactions ungrounded in reality. What does your experience say?

Comment: My experience says that this is a question with one error already, it could very easily have another. I would expect the unsaturated nitrile to be formed as there is some much driving force from the extended conjugation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129562/discussion-between-waylander-and-user55119).

Comment: @Waylander in the textbook answer to B is given Ph(CN)CH - CH(OH)Ph

Comment: That is the answer they want but it is not likely what actually happens under the conditions described.

Comment: Okay, got the point @user55119

Answer (score 3):

My answer will be somewhat contradicting that of @Waylander, but I believe it's correct since I know where the question has come from and have solved it before.

The first step with $\ce{KCN}$ substitutes $\ce{-Cl}$ group with $\ce{-CN}$ forming 2-phenylethanenitrile which is **A**

The next step is deprotonation of the benzyl carbon by a strong base, $\ce{EtO-}$ to give a carbanion which subsequently condenses with $\ce{PhCHO}$ by a nucleophilic addition on the carbonyl group. Like an aldol, it completes a dehydration of the $\ce{-OH}$ group to give $\ce{Ph(CN)C=CH-Ph}$ which is **B**.

The acidic medium and heating is for the hydrolysis of the $\ce{-CN}$ group to form $\ce{-COOH}$. The subequent steps with $\ce{SOCl2}$ and $\ce{MeNH2}$ are standard reactions.

(I should not be surprised if experimental evidence proves my answer to be completely wrong. But the exam this question is meant for is strictly theoretical and requires us to predict products of reactions in the same manner which I have followed. I know Waylander and user55119 are actual chemists whose answers and comments would be far more correct in reality.)

Comment: It is unclear from the reaction sequence drawn whetherD is made from C or from B. I took it that D is made from B. If the intention is that it is made from C then you are correct.

Comment: @Waylander I see your point now. As I said, I've done this question before, so it didn't cross my mind that the image formatting might make people think that it's going B to D directly. Of course, you're right that it looks ambiguous.

Comment: This is just a very poorly written question